# When Fragment onActivityCreated called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Before Google architecture component and `LiveData` I have not paid attention to `onActivityCreated()` callback.
I read about this here in SOF as well in documentation, and i still cannot understand the behavior.

From one of SOF answers:

> As the name states, this is called after the Activity's onCreate() has
> completed.

- In which conditions `onActivityCreated()` **called** and when `onActivityCreated()` **not called**?
- is it possible that `onCreateView()` called but `onActivityCreated()` not called?

It common practice to attach `LiveData` observers in `onActivityCreated()`, so i guess there are significant difference between `onActivityCreated()` and `onCreateView()`?

Although looking on the diagram from official Android docs seems like it `onActivityCreated()` is called **always** after `onCreateView()`(in terms of execution, not order) and there no diffrence?

Something confusing here.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
`onActivityCreated()` deprecated.

Comment: if you add fragment to `Activity` then recreate it (for example during orientation change) `FragmentManager` will recreate your fragment during activitys `onCreate` call.

Comment: They will never be reordered so `onActivityCreated` will always be called after `onViewCreated`. However it's not the case for headless fragments (returning `null` from `onCreateView`) in which case `onViewCreated` won't be called at all, but `onActivityCreated` will.

Comment: I am understand that they will never be reordered, but does `onActivityCreated` always executed after `onViewCreated` (in non for headless fragments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** According to Ian Lake on Twitter (see https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1193964829519667202), the fact that `FragmentActivity` attempts to dispatch `onActivityCreated` in `onStart` is irrelevant, because no matter what happens, the FragmentManager dispatches it anyway when going from `onCreate` to `onStart`.

> ```
>             case Fragment.CREATED:
>                 // We want to unconditionally run this anytime we do a moveToState that
>                 // moves the Fragment above INITIALIZING, including cases such as when
>                 // we move from CREATED => CREATED as part of the case fall through above.
>                 if (newState > Fragment.INITIALIZING) {
>                     fragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView();
>                 }
>                 if (newState > Fragment.CREATED) {
>                     fragmentStateManager.createView(mContainer);
>                     fragmentStateManager.activityCreated(); // <--
>                     fragmentStateManager.restoreViewState();
> ```

So what I said below is actually wrong.

Apparently using `onActivityCreated` inside a Fragment is equivalent to using `onViewCreated`.

But this also means you shouldn't rely on `onActivityCreated` to know if your Activity was actually created, because it is called more times than when the Activity is actually created.

Fragments are confusing.

---

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

> Is it possible that onCreateView() called but onActivityCreated() not called?

**UPDATE: No, it's not possible.**

**ORIGINAL:** Yes, in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` they use `FragmentTransaction.detach` / `FragmentTransaction.attach`, which causes the View to be destroyed, but the Fragment stays alive (stopped, but not destroyed).

In this case, `.attach()` runs `onCreateView`, but not `onActivityCreated`.

> It's common practice to attach LiveData observers in onActivityCreated(), so i guess there are significant difference between onActivityCreated() and onCreateView()?

**UPDATE: it doesn't matter, although `onViewCreated` is still clearer**.

**ORIGINAL:** It's actually a ***bad practice***, and should be done in `onViewCreated`, providing `getViewLifecycleOwner()` as the lifecycle owner.

> Although looking on the diagram from official Android docs seems like it onActivityCreated() is called always after onCreateView() and there no diffrence?

**UPDATE:** Despite that the `FragmentActivity` only tries to dispatch it once, all Fragments always go through `onActivityCreated`, because that's just how the FragmentManager works.

**ORIGINAL:** It is not always called after `onCreateView`, in fact, it's more-so called "before `onStart`, but only once".

> ```
> /**
>  * Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.
>  */
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>
>     mStopped = false;
>
>     if (!mCreated) {
>         mCreated = true;
>         mFragments.dispatchActivityCreated(); // <---
>     }
>
>     mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
>     mFragments.execPendingActions();
>
>     // NOTE: HC onStart goes here.
>
>     mFragments.dispatchStart();
> }
> ```

**UPDATE:** but apparently this doesn't really matter to the FragmentManager, because it goes `CREATED -> ACTIVITY_CREATED -> STARTED` either way.

Comment: @PavelPoley Status update: apparently Fragments are quirkier than what I claimed, and you should check the new status of this answer.